# Algorithm to optimally define groups based on multiple responses in R

Tags: r, algorithm, constraints, matching

I have a scheduling puzzle that I am looking for suggestions/solutions using R.

**Context**
I am coordinating a series of live online group discussions where registered participants will be grouped according to their availability. In a survey, 28 participants (id) indicated morning, afternoon, or evening (am, after, pm) availability on days Monday through Saturday (18 possibilities). I need to generate groups of 4-6 participants who are available at the same time, without replacement (meaning they can only be assigned to one group). Once assigned, groups will meet weekly at the same time (i.e. Group A members will always meet Monday mornings).

**Problem**
Currently group assignment is being achieved manually (by a human), but with more participants optimizing group assignment will become increasingly challenging. I am interested in finding an algorithm that efficiently achieves relatively equal group placements, and respects other factors such as a person's timezone.

**Sample Data**
Sample data are in long-format located in an R-script [here](https://gist.github.com/awfrankwils/3483236712538bf5841b2c3f5da72329).

```
>str(x)
'data.frame':   504 obs. of  4 variables:
$ id      : Factor w/ 28 levels "1","10","11",..: 1 12 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 2 ...
$ timezone: Factor w/ 4 levels "Central","Eastern",..: 2 1 3 4 2 1 3 4 2 1 ...
$ day.time: Factor w/ 18 levels "Fri.after","Fri.am",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
$ avail   : num  0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 ...
```

The first 12 rows of the data look like this:

```
> head(x, 12)
   id timezone  day.time avail
1   1  Eastern    Mon.am     0
2   2  Central    Mon.am     0
3   3 Mountain    Mon.am     1
4   4  Pacific    Mon.am     0
5   5  Eastern    Mon.am     1
6   6  Central    Mon.am     1
7   7 Mountain    Mon.am     0
8   8  Pacific    Mon.am     1
9   9  Eastern    Mon.am     0
10 10  Central    Mon.am     0
11 11 Mountain    Mon.am     0
12 12  Pacific    Mon.am     1
```

**Ideal Solution**
An algorithm to optimally define groups (size = 4 to 6) that exactly match on `day.time` and `avail` while minimizing differences on other more flexible factors (in this case `timezone`). In the final result, a participant should only exist in a single group.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I am not the most knowledge when it comes to this, but have you looked at the K-Means Clustering algorithm. You can specify the number of clusters you want and the variables for the algorithm to consider. It will then cluster the data into the specified number of clusters, aka, categories for you.

What do you think?

References:

https://datascienceplus.com/k-means-clustering-in-r/

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/cluster-analysis-in-r-unsupervised-machine-learning

Comment: It is an interesting suggestion; I also have no experience with k-means clustering. It would be great if someone could demonstrate how this might work with code.

Comment: A K-means solution requires all continuous variables. In this instance it would not be an appropriate method.

Comment: I think the biggest problem would be defining some sort of a distance measure between the different factors. With some feature engineering, you can come up with a numeric representation of the data. For timezone, it is possible to refactor them in their GMT representations, eg. -5, -7, +10, etc to convert them into numeric datatypes. For day.time, you can either directly convert them into factors or split them into day & time and provide some arbitrary values eg Mon = 1, Tues =2, etc for day and AM = -1, PM = 1 for time.